# Display non-related db content in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have a model without a db table used to display information that is stored in a session.

I am able to display the content in the session which was loaded from a given table using

```
$ids = Yii::app()->storedData->getIds();
foreach($ids as $id) {
echo 'ID '.$id .'<br />'; 
}
```

Instead of displaying the Ids I would rather display information from a related table of the table from which this info was loaded into the session.

To help explain what I am after, given:

[image]

I have ModelC to display session data that is loaded from TableA.  Currently with the code above the returned values are TableAId.  I would rather display TableB:Description instead.  How can I go about doing this without just loading that Description value into the session data too?

Comment: Why not just select needed descriptions by IDs ?

Comment: If the session data was more specific but I use the same behaviors to collect data from different tables.  Since in this one instance I want to pull up something different I didn't think that changing my logic in the session would be the best way.  Of course you may be right and I sure am open to suggestions.  If I can easily do this outside of the session I would like to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're after but if you want to be able to do:

```
echo $modelC->description;
```

And have the TableB description returned, just use a getter on the ModelC class:

```
class ModelC extends CModel{ // confusing ?
    public function getDescription(){
         return ModelB::model()->findByPk($this->tableBId);
    }
}
```

Is that what you were after?

Comment: In the above code I can retrieve a variable in the session in ModelC by using `$ids = Yii::app()->storedData->getIds();` say this gives me 48 which is TableAId. Instead of getting 48 I want to return the related description which is stored in TableB.  Does this help explain what I am after?

Comment: Yes. Instead of using `findByPk` you can use `findByAttributes` to compare the ID you have with column `TableAId` instead.

Comment: I appreciate your help here but I am unable to get that function to return anything in my view.   I have even tried to just get "48" to be replaced by another attribute in TableA to try and understand what is going on here but still not luck with that.  Do I need to add a comparison into my foreach statement?

Comment: Ok got it all working now with using findByAttributes, thanks again for the help!

Comment: Good glad you finally got it working. Not sure if you'll have read it but the official guide is fantastic: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.mvc